# Сбрасывается настройка MySQL

Tags: mysql, база-данных

В MySQL в "**Переменных**" вручную изменяю настройку **sql mode**, удаляя оттуда **ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY**, сохраняю. Далее все работает как нужно.

Но, через некоторое время, эта настройка сбрасывается и возвращается к исходному виду (снова появляется ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY изза чего на некоторых сайтах перестает работать определенный функционал).

**Вопрос**: почему это может происходить? Не могу понять совершенно..

Comment: *В MySQL в "Переменных"* Это, я извиняюсь, где? *изменяю настройку sql mode, удаляя оттуда ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY, сохраняю* Это надо делать в My.INI.

Comment: @Akina это через MyAdmin, вкладка Переменные, строка sql mode. В ней вручную удаляю ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY и сохраняю. Изначально все начинает функционировать, но через некоторое время эта настройка сбрасывается и ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY снова появляется в строке настройке (звучит несколько глупо, знаю, но просто излагаю факты, как оно получается на практике)

Comment: *В ней вручную удаляю ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY и сохраняю.* В лучшем случае при этом изменяется значение глобальной переменной, в худшем сессионной, но в любом случае - динамической. Настройку сервера таким образом изменить невозможно в принципе.

Comment: А как же правильно это сделать? Вручную в my.ini ?

Comment: Да. Альтернативный вариант - задать значение в командной строке запуска сервиса/демона. На сайтах на чужом хостинге и то, и другое нереально. В приложении (скриптовой части сайта) лучше при установлении соединения (а то и перед каждым запросом) изменять эту настройку. Именно для соединения.

Comment: @Akira сервер в данном случае, мой, поэтому изменить возможно к счастью все. Правда, изначально я пытался найти my.cnf и my.ini, но найти так и не смог. Поэтому, как альтернативу, и использовал этот вариант с изменением настройки через MyAdmin (решение нашел на англоязычном stackoverflow) Не подскажите, где этот файл может находится?

Или альтернативный вариант с командной строкой. Признаваться, не очень понял, какая для этого будет команда..

Comment: *Не подскажите, где этот файл может находится?* Не подскажу. Я же не знаю, какая версия MySQL-сервера, и на какой ОС... но точно знаю, что его местоположение описано в документации. *какая для этого будет команда* То же самое - в документации описано.

Comment: Прошу прощения. Версия сервера: 5.7.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.2 Если можете подсказать его местонахождение, буду очень признателен, или, как его возможно отыскать, т.к. в сети перечитал много сайтов, но ответа не нашел. Документация гласит, что он находится в /etc/mysql/my.cnf , однако это немного не так. У меня есть /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d и там mysqld.cnf с некоторыми настройками. Но как, и вообще в нем ли нужно менять эту настройку?

Comment: Убунта? вероятно, использовался DEB-package... В [Installing MySQL on Linux Using Debian Packages from Oracle](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/linux-installation-debian.html) пишут, что *All configuration files (like my.cnf) are under /etc/mysql*. И я в общем-то верю... на всякий пожарный см. в `SELECT @@basedir;`. Опять же у демона есть ключик `--init-file=file_name`... есть и впрямую ключик `--sql-mode=value[,value[,value...]]`... см. [Server Command Options](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html).